# Python - check if value exists in two separate lists

Tags: python

I created the following function

```
list1 = [6,2,3,8,1]
list2 = [9,3,5,2,1]

def value_in_both(list1,list2,value):
    return value in list1 and value in list2
```

`value_in_both(list1,list2,value)`

The code seems to work and basically shows if the value entered in the function exists in both lists by giving back True or False. However, I'm asking myself, if there is not a more efficient or different way to solve that problem. Does there exist a specific predefined function for that? Tried some other approaches which didn't work and couldn't find a function so far.

Cheers

Comment: Why would there be a predefined function for this? As you've proved, the language allows you to define it yourself in just one line anyway.

Comment: `set(list1)&set(list2)`

Comment: @mad_ and how does that test for membership of a particular, external value?

Comment: @roganjosh of course that is not the final output that is why I haven't posted as an answer but better than `in` operator. I know it is a dupe

Comment: @mad_ why compute the whole intersection? Why make two sets for one mebership test?

Comment: @timegb If both list values are constant and not variable.

Comment: There is nothing faster than `value in list1 and value in list2` if the test is performed only once. If this is repeated, then there are possible optimizations depending on information not available in the question. Anyway, optimizations should not be done until they are needed! (google "premature optimization")

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
intersection = set(list1).intersection(list2)
```

to have the common values between the two sets, 
then you can see

```
if value in intersection
```

Comment: This is slower than `value in list1 and value in list2` because it has to iterate over both lists and then compute an intersection and then hash `value`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this check often, keep two sets around for their O(1) membership test.

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
```

Do **not** create these sets inside of your function every time it is called, creating a set is an O(n) operation!

The fastest way to check whether a value `v` is in both of these set is `v in set1 and v in set2`.

Another possibility is `v in set1 & set2`, but `set1 & set2` is unnecessarily computing the complete intersection of both sets here.

If you want to read on, here's the [Time Complexity Reference](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for the builtin data structures.

edit: For very small lists, it's still possible that `v in list1 and v in list2` outperforms the sets. The lists will have no chance for lots of elements, though. You'll need to do some timings yourself with your actual data structures.

Comment: If list1 and list2 are constant then yes it is fine but if they are variable then you have to create different set

Comment: @mad_ yes, but maybe it is possible to use `set1` and `set2` throughout the code instead of the lists, if order and duplicated elements don't matter.

Comment: The whole point of defining a function is to consume the variable lists otherwise there is no need to define the function

Comment: @mad_ again, I am trying to point out that OP can improve the efficiency by using two sets as input for his function. If he must have two lists, which may or may not be mutated, then the sets don't apply.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I don't understand how exactly I would implement that into my function. As far as I understood I define both lists as sets. What do you mean with O(n)? Sorry I'm pretty new to Python..

Comment: @Lopoo O(n) in this conext means that the time for the `in` check grows linearly with the size of the list. O(1) means something runs in contant time, no matter the size of the data. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duvZ-2UK0fc) is an excellent introduction for the Big-O notation. As far as your function goes, I want you to pass it two sets instead of lists - if possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks great :) You can use sets, but constructing a set from a list is O(n), so unless you're gonna do more than just this one check, it's not worth it.